# Next Js getStaticProps issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, fetch-api

I am having trouble fetching posts from my WordPress site. I tested the URL endpoint and it appears to be working fine with client-side rendering. However, when I attempt to use the getStaticProps function, I'm not getting the results I expect. I have included the code I'm using below.

```
import { wpPosts } from "@/urls/indext";
import { Key } from "react";

const Blog = ({ data }: { data: any }) => {
  if (!data) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(
        (post: {
          id: Key | null | undefined;
          title: {
            rendered: string;
          };
          excerpt: { rendered: string };
          slug: string;
        }) => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h2>{post.title.rendered}</h2>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.excerpt.rendered }} />
            <a href={`/posts/${post.slug}`}>Read more</a>
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blog;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(wpPosts);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}
```

I did this approach few weeks ago while fetching pages from Wordpress, and everything was working fine. Now for this code I get Error:
TypeError: fetch failed.

When I wrap the fetch with try / catch block I get error like this:
Error serializing `.data` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/posts".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

And when I use null or any other type I don`t get error anymore but now the problem is that loading never stops.

I also tried axios and get:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:10052

Answer (score 0):

Since fetch is not available in NodeJS

please install [isomorphic-unfetch](https://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch) using the command

```
npm i isomorphic-unfetch
```

then use like below

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
```

PS: You can also use [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) if you need fully compatible fetch API in Node.JS but that is mostly going to be overkill in NextJS